# SharePoint 2013 - Downloading a copy of a file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

The following works so far in getting SharePoint to download a copy of a file:

```
http://spsite/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=http://spsite/Documents/test.docx
```

1. But is there a way I can add this link format to a publishing page without manually typing it out this way every time? Is JavaScript my only option?
2. Is there an alternative UI setting in SharePoint 2013 to download a copy of files for a  specific document library?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a hyperlink column and write a workflow to set the hyperlink based on the file name.

```
Set workflow variable (your hyperlink field) to http://spsite/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=http://spsite/Documents/[%CurrentItem:Name%], [%CurrentItem:Name%]
Set field in current item (your hyperlink field) to Variable:link
```

This sets the URL and the content after the comma in the workflow variable is the link's display text.

Comment: Thanks can you provide a basic example or test process of what you mean.   Google can't even give me something simple on this....

Comment: I just realized you can't use file name in a calculated field. I changed my answer to steps for a workflow to set a hyperlink field to your download link.

Comment: A workflow may be suitable but I can't use SharePoint Designer at the moment due to external reasons.  +1 Thank you for researching this though.

Comment: Then yes, I would say you're stuck with javascript, but I would still create a hyperlink field, but hide and set it using the javascript on the NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx pages. Let me know if you need help with that. I can walk you through in chat sometime tomorrow.